# Sql server subquery to be rewritten using Joins

Tags: sql-server

I have this pasted subquery and i need to rewrite it using only joins ( no subquery).

Tried multiple times for close to a month but in vain.
Request you to help me out.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_user WHERE userId NOT IN 
(SELECT u.userId FROM wp_user as u, wp_luncher as i, wp_subscription as s
WHERE u.userId = i.luncherId
and i.luncherId = s.luncherid)
and CreationDate between '20181001' and '20181015';
```

**Tables involved :-**

```
CREATE TABLE wp_user (
userId int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
userName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
CreationDate date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE wp_luncher (
luncherId int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
parentId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES wp_user(userId)
);

CREATE TABLE wp_subscription (
SubId int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
luncherId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES wp_luncher(luncherId)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query.

You can use OUTER APPLY.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_user wp
OUTER APPLY
(
   SELECT i.luncherId
   FROM  wp_luncher as i, wp_subscription as s
   WHERE  i.luncherId = wp.userId 
          and i.luncherId = s.luncherid
) I
WHERE I.luncherId IS NOT NULL
and CreationDate between '20181001' and '20181015';
```

Another option inserts the subquery's data into a table variable.

```
DECLARE @TempTable AS TABLE (UserId INT)
INSERT INTO @TempTable
SELECT i.luncherId
FROM  wp_luncher as i, wp_subscription as s
WHERE  i.luncherId = s.luncherid


SELECT * 
FROM wp_user wp
LEFT JOIN @TempTable I ON I.UserId = wp.userId
WHERE I.UserId IS NOT NULL
and CreationDate between '20181001' and '20181015';
```